# How to invite facebook user's friends to event?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to create event under user's name in application and invite his friends to it. How to to do this in application? I know how to get users by that:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
```

Thanks for any  help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this docs to know how to create event:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing.

In a nutshell you should issue HTTP POST request with required params:

> /PROFILE_ID/events

with  params **name**, **start_time**, **end_time**.

Check out this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#invited for info about inviting.

It's all about issuing POST request

> /EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3

with multiple users ids you want to invite.

Comment: Could you present some sample code? It would be very helpful :)